# How to call a function in cubit class in initState?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-state, cubit

So, I have made a function in Cubit Class it is to get data from API. For now I just can get the data if I pressed a button. I wanna make the function automatically called when the page/screen is open. For your information, this page is the first page that will be launched when user open the app. Here is some of my codes.

```
class UsersCubit extends Cubit<UsersState> {
  UsersCubit() : super(UsersInitial());

  UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();

  void getAllUsers() async{
    emit(UsersLoading());
    try{
      ResponseUsers _data = await _userRepository.getUsers();
      emit(UsersSuccess(_data));
    } catch(e){
      emit(UsersError(e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

```
class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UsersPageState createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Users")),
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => UsersCubit(),
        child: BlocConsumer<UsersCubit, UsersState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if(state is UsersLoading){
              print("getting users ...");
            } else if (state is UsersSuccess){
              print(state.data.users[1].identity!.name);
            } else if (state is UsersError){
              print(state.errorMessage);
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                (state is UsersSuccess) ? listViewUsers(state.data.users) : progressBar(),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    context.read<UsersCubit>().getAllUsers();
                  },
                  child: Text("GET USERS"),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to call the function directly in `initState` but when I run the app it returns an error.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<UsersCubit>().getAllUsers();
    super.initState();
  }
```

error:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<UsersCubit> above this UsersPage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that UsersPage is under your MultiProvider/Provider<UsersCubit>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ...
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ...

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ...
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
```

Is there any way to solve this case?

Comment: can you share your code ? which have BlocProvider for UsersCubit and class use this Cubit ?

Comment: Since you're using Cubit, you're locked in to BloC.  So short answer: I can't help you.  Longer answer: if BloC is the *ONLY* state management you're using with Flutter, then *PLEASE* consider alternative approaches.  Very often, you don't need anything more complex than [StatefulWidget](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/stateful-widget-lifecycle).  You *SELDOM* need anything more complex than [Provider](https://dzone.com/articles/flutter-20-state-management-introduction-with-prov).  Flutter provides many - great! - choices.  Use the "best tool for the job" :)

Comment: PS: `when I run the app it returns an error...`: PLEASE UPDATE YOUR POST WITH THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE!

Comment: i hava updated the post @dangngocduc

Comment: you should wrap the parent widget with the BlocProvider.

Comment: the Scaffold? or MaterialApp? @Hamed

Comment: Provide your cubit above the ```MaterialApp``` and you can access it from everywhere inside your app.

Comment: @EhsanAskari thank you so much! It works for my case!

Answer (score 6):

Can you try wrapp `BlocConsumer` inside a `Builder` ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UsersPageState createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Users")),
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) {
          final cubit = UsersCubit();
          cubit.getAllUsers();
          return cubit;
        },
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return BlocConsumer<UsersCubit, UsersState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if(state is UsersLoading){
                print("getting users ...");
              } else if (state is UsersSuccess){
                print(state.data.users[1].identity!.name);
              } else if (state is UsersError){
                print(state.errorMessage);
              }
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  (state is UsersSuccess) ? listViewUsers(state.data.users) : progressBar(),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      context.read<UsersCubit>().getAllUsers();
                    },
                    child: Text("GET USERS"),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have just tried it and it returns same error

Comment: I have just update solution, you can try my code again?

Comment: this case is solved already :)

Answer (score 6):

You **don't** need to call a function inside initState when using Bloc or cubit, just call it when creating the Cubit inside BlocProvider like this >>.

```
class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UsersPageState createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Users")),
      body: BlocProvider(
        /// after create the cubit you can call the method.
        create: (context) => UsersCubit()..getAllUsers();,
        child: BlocConsumer<UsersCubit, UsersState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if(state is UsersLoading){
              print("getting users ...");
            } else if (state is UsersSuccess){
              print(state.data.users[1].identity!.name);
            } else if (state is UsersError){
              print(state.errorMessage);
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                (state is UsersSuccess) ? listViewUsers(state.data.users) : progressBar(),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    context.read<UsersCubit>().getAllUsers();
                  },
                  child: Text("GET USERS"),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can call it from your Blocprovider by accessing your class like this :-

```
 BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => Usercubit()..getAllUsers(),
      build : (context) => Scaffold() ........
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this case with help from @Ehsan Askari. He suggests me to provide the cubit above the MaterialApp, then I did it. Here is my code now

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => UsersCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: UsersPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class UsersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UsersPageState createState() => _UsersPageState();
}

class _UsersPageState extends State<UsersPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<UsersCubit>().getAllUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Users")),
      body: BlocConsumer<UsersCubit, UsersState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if(state is UsersLoading){
            print("getting users ...");
          } else if (state is UsersSuccess){
            print(state.data.users[1].identity!.name);
          } else if (state is UsersError){
            print(state.errorMessage);
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return (state is UsersSuccess) ? listViewUsers(state.data.users) : progressBar();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```